# Is there a similar concept to standard normal distribution in the context of joint probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The simplest case of a normal distribution is known as the [standard normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution)

which is described by this probability density function:

${\displaystyle \varphi (x)={\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi }}}e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}x^{2}}}$

this is for one random variable.

how about 2 random variables, namely, is there a similar concept for joint probability, something like standard normal joint probability distribution?

I've [searched](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22standard%20normal%20joint%20probability%20distribution%22) this on math.stackexchange.com and got '0 results'.

any clue?

Comment: Take i.i.d standard normal variables.

Comment: Something like a [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called **The Standard Bivariate Normal Distribution**

a pair of independent random variables X and Y, each follows the standard normal distribution ${\displaystyle X \sim \ {\mathcal {N}}(0,1)}$, and ${\displaystyle Y \sim \ {\mathcal {N}}(0,1)}$

For a constant $\rho$ with $-1< \rho <1$, define random variables

[image]

and then

[image]

more info is [here](http://www.stat.yale.edu/~pollard/Courses/241.fall97/Multinormal.pdf).